# Test whether the data belong to certain data type in C++?

Tags: c++, types, runtime

```
datatype *x;//where datatype is a class defined earlier;
//...

if (isDataType(x[0]))//test whether x[0] belong to datatype defined.

//do something
```

Is there any C++ function can do job like above?

Comment: What are you asking? Why don't you know what type `x` is?  Is it a template argument? is `datatype` a polymorphic type? Are you trying to tell if it really points to a `datatype` because some idiot might have made it point to the wrong type with evil casts?

Comment: Yes, x is a template argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isDataType(const datatype&) { return true; }

template<typename T> bool isDataType(const T&) { return false; }
```

probably not what you really want though ...

Comment: Why? the example here looks like the other way also could work: cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_same, btw, x is a template argument, I have not finish writing the templates yet, but do you think by using such functions to tell the data type of x (then, based on the data type, go different pathes), the codes can be compiled successfully?

Comment: Thank you for correcting the mistake, I just googled the is_same function, and I see the function works the way I want,  have not seen the first answer's other arguments, the answer should be something like std::is_same<datatype, x[0]>::value or something.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```
#include <type_traits>

if ( std::is_same<datatype, decltype(x[0])>::value ) {

}
```

Comment: Many thanks, just googled that function, thats exact what I am asking for.

Comment: Isn't that always `true`? If `X` is a pointer to `datatype`, then `X[0]` is `datatype`. Thus, it should boil down to `std::is_same<datatype, datatype>::value`, doesn't it?

Comment: @user1748356 Are you sure this does what you want? You should see Philipp's comment.

Comment: Do you mean `std::is_same<datatype,decltype(x[0])>::value`?

Comment: Erm, but `decltype(x[0])` is `datatype&`

Comment: @jonathanWakely Does simply doing `x[0]` suffice?

Comment: just an example, of cause x could be something else instead of datatype...like static_cast<>...

Comment: @David I don't understand the question.

Comment: well, maybe thats just I have not explained well, I just ask functions to tell whether some variable x belong a specific data type.

Comment: Then see my answer (this one doesn't work, it would need to be something like  `std::is_same<datatype, std::decay<decltype(x[0])>::type>::value`)

Comment: Why? the exmaple here works like it could work: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_same/

Comment: I already said: `decltype(x[0])` is `datatype&` which is not the same as `datatype` so the test will never be true